# Updating SQLite table with Python function using table columns as arguments

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to `UPDATE` all records of a table with the results of a function which uses the other rows of the table as arguments. However, the result of this operation for all records is repeated from the first record. Can anyone explain why this might be the case?

```
def fun(a,b,c,d):
    return a + b + c + d

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT field1, field2, field3, field4 FROM TABLE1")

for row in cur:
        cur.execute("UPDATE TABLE1 SET field5 = ?", (fun(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3]),))
```

The completed table looks like this:

```
field1, field2, field3, field4, field5
4, 3, 2, 1, 10
7, 3, 1, 0, 10
8, 5, 2, 0, 10
```

When it should look like this:

```
field1, field2, field3, field4, field5
4, 3, 2, 1, 10
7, 3, 1, 0, 11
8, 5, 2, 0, 15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you select all of the rows:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3, field4 FROM TABLE1
```

This yields this result set in `cur`:

```
4, 3, 2, 1
7, 3, 1, 0
8, 5, 2, 0
```

You begin to iterate through the rows. You start with the first row:

```
4, 3, 2, 1
```

You add all the columns together, correctly yielding the result `10`. Then you execute this SQL statement:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET field5 = 10
```

Whoa, there! There's no `where` clause! You've just changed `field5` of *every single row*! That's problem #1: **you need to add a `where` clause**. Most tables have a primary key, so if you have a primary key, you'll probably want to add a clause like `where id = ?`. If you don't have a primary key, probably the best you can do is include all the other columns, e.g.

```
update table1
set field5 = ?
where field1 = ?
and field2 = ?
and field3 = ?
and field4 = ?
```

Make sure that you provide a value for each `?` in the `execute` call.

---

So you've finished executing your `update` statement on the `cur` cursor. You go to iterate again… and there's no more rows. Why? Because that `update` statement changed the result set of the cursor, discarding the remaining rows of the `select`. **You need to run your updates on a different cursor or fetch all the rows before you move on to updating.**

Comment: Using a second cursor makes sense and is easy to apply. However, could you clarify what the `where` clause should be stating? Something like 'where record count += 1'?

Comment: @user1185790: You'll have to find some set of columns to uniquely identify that row. I've updated my answer to clarify that.

Comment: Ok, I'll accept your answer because I'm sure you're right. Unfortunately, I'm encountering the error message "sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 1 supplied." when applying the following: cur = conn.cursor(), cur.execute("SELECT field1, field2, field3, field4 FROM TABLE1"), cur1 = conn.cursor(), for row in cur: cur1.execute("UPDATE TABLE1 SET field5 = ? WHERE field1 = ?", (fun(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3]),)). I'm sure it's some silly issue I'm overlooking, so I'll try to diagnose that problem since it's a separate issue

Comment: @user1185790: When you have two `?` in the query, you need another thing in the tuple passed as the second argument to `execute`, e.g., `cur1.execute("update table1 set field5 = ? where field1 = ?", (calculate(...), row[0]))`.

Comment: Ah! I got it. Thank you so much for your patience. This was wrapped in a tuple and it worked: (fun(int(row[0]),int(row[1]),int(row[2]),int(row[3])),row[0]))

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old and solved issue but I can't help it:

That is the worse way to update a table with values form its own columns. All you need to do is one single update statement executed in the database:

```
UPDATE table SET 
field1 = function(params1), 
field2=function(params2),   
field3=function(params3),   
field4=function(params4)
WHERE
<condition>
```

The where clause is not needed if you want to do that for all the rows in your table. The only thing you need to do is to define a user function within your database, which is pretty similar with what you would do in python.

This way the update will be about ... 1000 times faster, with no exaggeration.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the function to your database:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")

def fun(a,b,c,d):
    return a + b + c + d

conn.create_function(
cur = conn.cursor('fun', 4, fun)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("UPDATE table SET field5 = fun(field1, field2, field3, field4)")
```